# random http 400 errors when retrieving file

Tags: c++, http, mfc

I develop an MFC app.  On startup, it retrieves the contents of an xml file from our website.  It has been doing this without problems for years, but lately we are getting 400 "Bad Request" errors.  The code boils down to this:

---

```
#include "afxinet.h"
void TestWebAccess(const CString& sPathname)
{
    CInternetSession iSess;
    int nType = INTERNET_FLAG_TRANSFER_ASCII | INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD;
    CStdioFile* pFile = iSess.OpenURL(sPathname, 1, nType);

    DWORD dwStatusCode = 0;
    BOOL bOK = ((CHttpFile*)pFile)->QueryInfoStatusCode(dwStatusCode);
    if (bOK && dwStatusCode == 400) {
        TRACE("400 ERROR: %s\n", sPathname);
    }
}
```

---

This error doesn't happen every time, just randomly every few tries.  This rules out a lot of possible explanations, like any problem in the pathname -- the app passes the exact same data every time, but only sometimes gets the error.

Grasping at straws, I captured packet activity using WinDump.  Here is an excerpt from a successful run, followed by a bad one:

--- good ---

```
IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 22607, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 162, bad cksum 0 (->c092)!) 10.0.0.3.52244 > 66.96.149.17.80: P 1:123(122) ack 1 win 65535
 ..GET /WebDL2/upgrades_70_TEST.xml HTTP/1.1
IP (tos 0x20, ttl  50, id 33347, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 40) 66.96.149.17.80 > 10.0.0.3.52244: ., cksum 0x3898 (correct), 1:1(0) ack 123 win 29200
IP (tos 0x20, ttl  50, id 33348, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 485) 66.96.149.17.80 > 10.0.0.3.52244: P 1:446(445) ack 123 win 29200
 ..HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

--- bad ---

```
IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 22674, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 155, bad cksum 0 (->c056)!) 10.0.0.3.52258 > 66.96.149.17.80: P 1:116(115) ack 1 win 65535
 ..GET /WebDL2/upgrades_70_TEST.xml HTTP/1.1
IP (tos 0x20, ttl  50, id 33318, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 40) 66.96.149.17.80 > 10.0.0.3.52258: ., cksum 0xca8a (correct), 1:1(0) ack 116 win 29200
IP (tos 0x20, ttl  50, id 33319, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 469) 66.96.149.17.80 > 10.0.0.3.52258: P 1:430(429) ack 116 win 29200
 ..HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

---

I have just the barest knowledge of TCP, and don't understand all of this.  Is there anything about that second request which merits a 400 error?

Other notes about the problem:

1. If I extract this code into a separate stand-alone app, the problem doesn't happen.  It happens (sometimes) if I call this code from our app, near the beginning of InitInstance.
2. There is no problem pasting the target url into a browser -- the xml page never fails to come up.
3. The problem has been reported by users in the field, running a previous version of our app.  Which leads me to think it could be something suddenly wrong on the server rather than any recent changes in our code.
4. It's not just this particular xml file which gets the error -- I've tried a bunch of them, they all behave the same way.
5. The server is a public domain host (netfirms.com), so I have no control over it and can't experiment on it.  And so far their tech support has been of the "did you try unplugging it" variety.  They don't see any problems on their end.

I am at my wit's end.  We were about a day from going out with our new release after over a year of development, then all of a sudden this comes along.  I'm grateful for any ideas.

-- Jim

Thanks for the response.  Go easy on me, will ya?  I never had to look at this stuff before.  Here are another good and bad chunk, with more info.

```
--- good ---
IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 23479, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 155, bad cksum 0 (->bd31)!) 10.0.0.3.57929 > 66.96.149.17.80: P 1:116(115) ack 1 win 65535
    0x0000:  0000 ca11 2233 0025 64a1 6f2b 0800 4500  ...."3.%d.o+..E.
    0x0010:  009b 5bb7 4000 8006 0000 0a00 0003 4260  ..[.@.........B`
    0x0020:  9511 e249 0050 6b28 f0d4 8fd1 31c9 5018  ...I.Pk(....1.P.
    0x0030:  ffff e201 0000 4745 5420 2f57 6562 444c  ......GET./WebDL
    0x0040:  322f 7570 6772 6164 6573 5f37 305f 5445  2/upgrades_70_TE
    0x0050:  5354 2e78 6d6c 2048 5454 502f 312e 310d  ST.xml.HTTP/1.1.
IP (tos 0x20, ttl  50, id 32642, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 40) 66.96.149.17.80 > 10.0.0.3.57929: ., cksum 0x5bab (correct), 1:1(0) ack 116 win 29200
    0x0000:  0025 64a1 6f2b 0000 ca11 2233 0800 4520  .%d.o+...."3..E.
    0x0010:  0028 7f82 4000 3206 e7b9 4260 9511 0a00  .(..@.2...B`....
    0x0020:  0003 0050 e249 8fd1 31c9 6b28 f147 5010  ...P.I..1.k(.GP.
    0x0030:  7210 5bab 0000 0000 cd54 f0b3            r.[......T..
IP (tos 0x20, ttl  50, id 32643, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 485) 66.96.149.17.80 > 10.0.0.3.57929: P 1:446(445) ack 116 win 29200
    0x0000:  0025 64a1 6f2b 0000 ca11 2233 0800 4520  .%d.o+...."3..E.
    0x0010:  01e5 7f83 4000 3206 e5fb 4260 9511 0a00  ....@.2...B`....
    0x0020:  0003 0050 e249 8fd1 31c9 6b28 f147 5018  ...P.I..1.k(.GP.
    0x0030:  7210 dd6f 0000 4854 5450 2f31 2e31 2032  r..o..HTTP/1.1.2
    0x0040:  3030 204f 4b0d 0a44 6174 653a 2053 756e  00.OK..Date:.Sun
    0x0050:  2c20 3130 204d 6172 2032 3031 3920 3032  ,.10.Mar.2019.02


--- bad ---
IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 23474, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 171, bad cksum 0 (->bd26)!) 10.0.0.3.57928 > 66.96.149.17.80: P 1:132(131) ack 1 win 65535
    0x0000:  0000 ca11 2233 0025 64a1 6f2b 0800 4500  ...."3.%d.o+..E.
    0x0010:  00ab 5bb2 4000 8006 0000 0a00 0003 4260  ..[.@.........B`
    0x0020:  9511 e248 0050 d41f f5a8 1b81 c914 5018  ...H.P........P.
    0x0030:  ffff e211 0000 4745 5420 2f57 6562 444c  ......GET./WebDL
    0x0040:  322f 7570 6772 6164 6573 5f37 305f 5445  2/upgrades_70_TE
    0x0050:  5354 2e78 6d6c 2048 5454 502f 312e 310d  ST.xml.HTTP/1.1.
IP (tos 0x20, ttl  50, id 33346, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 40) 66.96.149.17.80 > 10.0.0.3.57928: ., cksum 0xc7a5 (correct), 1:1(0) ack 132 win 30016
    0x0000:  0025 64a1 6f2b 0000 ca11 2233 0800 4520  .%d.o+...."3..E.
    0x0010:  0028 8242 4000 3206 e4f9 4260 9511 0a00  .(.B@.2...B`....
    0x0020:  0003 0050 e248 1b81 c914 d41f f62b 5010  ...P.H.......+P.
    0x0030:  7540 c7a5 0000 0000 4778 f4ff            u@......Gx..
IP (tos 0x20, ttl  50, id 33347, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 469) 66.96.149.17.80 > 10.0.0.3.57928: P 1:430(429) ack 132 win 30016
    0x0000:  0025 64a1 6f2b 0000 ca11 2233 0800 4520  .%d.o+...."3..E.
    0x0010:  01d5 8243 4000 3206 e34b 4260 9511 0a00  ...C@.2..KB`....
    0x0020:  0003 0050 e248 1b81 c914 d41f f62b 5018  ...P.H.......+P.
    0x0030:  7540 8572 0000 4854 5450 2f31 2e31 2034  u@.r..HTTP/1.1.4
    0x0040:  3030 2042 6164 2052 6571 7565 7374 0d0a  00.Bad.Request..
    0x0050:  4461 7465 3a20 5375 6e2c 2031 3020 4d61  Date:.Sun,.10.Ma
```

Comment: The length of the two packets is different, 155 vs 162 bytes; but the shown data is identical in both cases, just the requested URI, which is far less than the 155-162 bytes. The shown data is incomplete, and, therefore, the difference must be in the data that's not shown, and it's unlikely that anyone will be able to figure out any problem in some data that's not even shown.

Comment: See additional data above.  The stuff before the readable ascii request was indecipherable to me.  Can you get something from it?

Comment: The stuff before the readable part is the IP header, which is irrelevant. The readable part, the actual HTTP request is cut off. There's more past that point. "length=155", for example, but only the first 96 bytes of that are shown. The last logged byte is CR, `0d`, at the end of the request line, however that's always followed by LF, `0a`. At this point, I expect to see a difference in the HTTP requests. After you figure out what the rest of it, you should be able to see the problem yourself, the difference in the HTTP requests, which will be your answer.

Comment: Thanks Sam.  It looks like a bad request includes a **User-Agent** item, and its value is a number (not readable ascii), whereas a good request includes no such item.  Next I'll see if I can figure out where that's coming from.  Hints invited.

Comment: RESOLUTION!  Turns out the first arg of the CInternetSession constructor is the desired user-agent name.  If not supplied, then it defaults to whatever AfxGetAppName returns.  Which turned out to be random garbage when called too early in the process.  Solution: supply my app name in the constructor.

Comment: PS.  Sam: beer's on me if we ever meet :-)

Comment: Free beer always gets an upvote from me.